# Problems Adding Shopify Line Items to Cart with JS Buy SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, shopify

Having some problems with the Shopify js-buy-SDK.

I have been able to make a cart, and I have also tried fetching products, etc, and it works. But when I try to add a line item to the cart, the updated cart array, from addLineItems, returns empty.  I know the variantId is correct, because if I change it I get an error.

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/js-buy-sdk/v1/latest/index.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    const client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
          domain: 'xxxx.myshopify.com',
          storefrontAccessToken: 'xxxxxxx',
          appId: '6'
    });
    // Create an empty checkout
    client.checkout.create().then((checkout) => {
       // Do something with the checkout
       console.log(checkout.id);
       x(checkout.id, client);

    });

});

function x(check, client) {
        const itemToAdd = [
            { variantId : 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzYyMDExMDQxMzg4NA==', quantity : 12 }
            ];

        // Add an item to the checkout
        client.checkout.addLineItems(check, itemToAdd).then((checkout) => {
            console.log(checkout.lineItems); // THIS RETURNS AN EMPTY ARRAY
        }); 
}
</script>

</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the productID or the variantID of the item you're trying to add?

In my experience, if an ID ends with `==` it's a productID.

Assuming the item you're trying to add only has one variant, try

```
const productId = 'Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzYyMDExMDQxMzg4NA==';

client.product.fetch(productId)
.then((product) => {
    const variantId = product.variants[0].id;
    console.log(variantId);
});
```

If you're seeing an ID-like string and not `undefined` in your console then that is the correct value for your variantID.

Comment: Is it possible to add item using product ID? @Bossan

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet No, it's not unfortunately. All Products have one ProductVariant by default.